# XPages OpenLog - Logging to wrong database

Tags: xpages

Apologies Paul, this is a duplicate to the post I put on OpenNTF, however the site will not allow me to log in the last 2 days to follow up, plus the wider audience of Stack might find me someone with an identical issue.

To keep it short.

I have 1 openLog database in a folder structure, logs/xpageslog.nsf

During development, I could log to this database, for example, using Paul Withers XPages OpenLog Logger, to log uncaught exceptions with the following settings:

```
private String logDbName = "logs\\xpageslog.nsf"; // in OpenLogItem.java from OpenLogClass library

logDbName = "logs/xpages.nsf" // in OpenLogFunctions.ls

xsp.openlog.filepath=log/xpageslog.nsf // in xsp.properties
```

However, if I then change all the above, to simply go to xpageslog.nsf, in the root of the server (this is a 2nd openLog database) errors still get logged to the first database.

I've tried building, cleaning, re-compiling, all to no avail. It seem's to be that somewhere, or somehow, the references to the original database are not being overwritten.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you restarted http after the changes?

Comment: I did try that on the live server, and it didn't work, just checking the log, Issued a "tell http restart"..... However will try again on DEV now. EDIT: Just restarted, and no joy

Comment: Have you been able to confirm which OpenLog library is trying to log to the wrong location - LS, Java, XPages or all? Also, whether it's this specific database or another that's triggering the error that's trying to log to the wrong location. It's worth making sure you're trying to fix it in the right place.

Comment: @ChrisRichards It is good practice to use `restart task http` instead of `tell http restart`. Both commands have different effects.

Comment: @FrantisekKossuth, did you want to submit that as an answer for me to accept as that's done the trick! I notice the main difference in the log with the 2 commands relates to the installation of the osgi plugins, so I assume that's why I needed the "hard" restart as Pauls XPages OpenLogLogger is installed via my update site?

Comment: @ChrisRichards Done. Thanks in advance for accepting it as answer.

Comment: I have a similar problem, although using OpenNTF Domino API. I hope you have found an answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75223020/xpages-log-messages-from-applications-land-in-incorrect-database-despite-diffe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is good practice to use `restart task http` instead of `tell http restart`. Both commands have different effects.

As confirmed in comments, this solved the problem.

Some use `tell http quit` followed by `load http`, the effect is the same as with `restart task http`. At the other hand, simple `tell http restart` does not fully initialize http task, it's kind of soft reset and I recommend not using it.